# How to overide the geo IP Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, geolocation, magento-1.7

I currently have a Geo-redirect set up in my htaccess to redirect user say from Asia who visits example.com to asia.example.com. I am now wondering how to override that redirection so users from asia.example.com can get to example.com through a link on asia.example.com.

Is that possible or do I have to use a client-side redirect and how would I go about setting that up.

And some background info example.com is running Magento and asia.example.com will be a landing page for now.

Thanks

Update: My host says I should install this https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php on Magento... How would I do that?

Update from comment:

```
# Redirect multiple countries to a single page
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(VN|SG|CN|MY|JP|KP|KR)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ asia.example.com$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Please show your redirect code from `.htaccess`

Comment: # Redirect multiple countries to a single page
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(VN|SG|CN|MY|JP|KP|KR)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://asia.example.com$1 [R,L]

Answer (score 0):

Normally Magento offers a store switcher in the form of a select field, see it working on [demo.magentocommerce.com](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/).  The theme in use might change how this is displayed, it could be a link or button instead but the principle is the same, a `store` cookie is written with the store code as it's value.  We can test for that directly in `.htaccess` and avoid GeoIP if present.

```
# Redirect multiple countries to a single page
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(VN|SG|CN|MY|JP|KP|KR)$

# New cookie condition goes here
# ! means true when it doesn't match
# \b means word boundary
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !\bstore=default\b

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ asia.example.com$1 [R,L]
```

---

It is necessary for the cookie to be transmitted on every request or the user might find themselves being redirected later.  You may have to set the cookie domain to `.example.com` (note the leading period) if it misbehaves.  You can do this in Magento's admin under *System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management.*  This allows the cookie to be written by `asia.example.com` and be read by `example.com`, and vice versa.

If you want to make a link instead of the store switcher then use [`Mage::getUrl`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters) in this way, it will generate an URL with a `___store` query parameter:

```
<?php
    $url = Mage::getUrl('', array(
        '_store' => 'default',
        '_store_to_url' => true
    ));
?>
<a href="<?php echo $url ?>"><?php echo $this->__('International Store') ?></a>
```

Comment: Thanks very much but here's another problem the asia.example.com as mentioned above is a landing page :( It does not run magento right now but I need away for users after getting redirected to go back to the original domain example.com if needed.

Comment: Then the landing page would need a link to `//example.com/?___store=default` which is the minimum you can get away with.